# Exercise 3, Section 4.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix over the field $F$, i.e. a matrix satisfying $A_{ij} = 0$ for $i\neq j$. Let $j$ be the polynomial over $F$ defined by $f=(x-A_{11})\dotsb (x-A_{nn})$. What is the matrix $f(A)$?

Before start solving problem I want to understand problem. How is $f=(x-A_{11})\dotsb (x-A_{nn})$ a polynomial, where $x=(0,1,0,…)$? Because $x-A_{ii}$ don’t make sense. $f$ is not in form of a polynomial i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i\cdot x^i$, for some $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Similarly $A-A_{ii}$ don’t make sense in $f(A)=(A-A_{11})\dotsb (A-A_{nn})$.

Comment: I read it as $x$ being the matrix valued variable. You can subtract to matrices, they're vectors.

Comment: @CyclotomicField there is precise definition of $f(A)$.

Comment: The $A_{ij}$ are scalars.

Comment: @JohnDouma yep matrix $A$ is fixed. I think answer below answer my question about $x-A_{ii}$ is actually $x-A_{ii}x^i$. Can you please tell why $f$ is a polynomial?  Certainly it don’t looks like a polynomial, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(A) = (A - A_{11}I)\cdots(A - A_{nn}I)$$ where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I wanna ask, how $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: @user264745 $n \times n$ matrices form a ring and you can define polynomials with coefficients from any ring so here that's the matrices.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I haven’t yet reach definition of ring. By definition of $f(A)$, it is in $M_n(F)$. It’s easy to check $M_n(F)$ is a linear algebra with identity over $F$.

Comment: @user264745 a ring is just a field without multiplicative inverses or commutativity.

Comment: @CyclotomicField In Hoffman’s book, precise definition of $f(A)$ is given. I’m trying to ask how $f=(x-A_{11})…(x-A_{nn})$ is a polynomial. I mean $f$ is not in it’s standard form, i.e. $f=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i x^i$.

Comment: @user264745 If $A_{11}$ is a scalar you're done, otherwise this answer is probably correct. It's not uncommon to see the identity matrix suppressed like $1$ would be in matrix polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to look at a simple example. If
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$
then $A_{11}=1$ and $A_{22}=2$, so
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)=x^2-3x+2$$
The important thing to see here is that $f$ is still a polynomial in $x$ even if we express it as a product of linear factors, rather than in standard form. We can always expand it to the standard form.

Notice in this example that
$$\begin{align*}f(A)&=A^2-3A+2I\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}1^2&0\\0&2^2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-3\cdot 1&0\\0&-3\cdot 2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}f(1)&0\\0&f(2)\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\\
&=0\end{align*}$$

In the general case of an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix $A$ with $f(x)=(x-A_{11})\cdots(x-A_{nn})$, we also have
$$f(A)=\begin{bmatrix}f(A_{11})&&\\&\ddots&\\&&f(A_{nn})\end{bmatrix}=0$$
In fact, $f(x)=\det(xI-A)$ is just the characteristic polynomial of $A$, and the fact that $f(A)=0$ is just a special case of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, as you will see later in the book.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. $(x-1)(x-2)=x^2-3x+2$ follows from the definition of linear algebra over $F$, though we’re writing it as $x$ is a real number, I mean it has similar property as real number. I find $f(A)$ by solving $A^2-3\cdot A+2\cdot I$ equation. How do you get “shortcut” $f(A)= \begin{bmatrix}f(1)&0\\0&f(2)\end{bmatrix}$ and you easily generalize to $n\in \Bbb{N}$?

Comment: For the shortcut think about what happens to  diagonal matrices when you scale them, add them to each other, and raise them to powers. Then think about what $f$ does.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t get it. Can you please explain it thoroughly?

Comment: I edited my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Now it makes sense. But I can’t generalize to $n\in \Bbb{N}$, i.e. if $f(x)=(x-A_{11}\cdot (1,0,0,…))\dotsb ((x-A_{nn}\cdot (1,0,0,…))$, then $f(A)=\begin{bmatrix}f(A_{11})&&\\&\ddots&\\&&f(A_{nn})\end{bmatrix}=0$. I tried to use induction. I proved for base case $n=2$, $f(x)=(x-A_{11})…(x-A_{22})$ $=x^2-(A_{11}+A_{22})\cdot x + A_{11}A_{22}$. Then $f(A)=A^2-(A_{11}+A_{22})\cdot A+ A_{11}A_{22}\cdot I$ $=\begin{bmatrix}f(A_{11}\cdot I)&0\\0&f(A_{22}\cdot I)\end{bmatrix}=0$. How to prove inductive step?